# How to use infinite type specifiers in scanf() function in C?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I want to use infinite type specifiers (%c) in scanf() function.

For example-

```
printf("Enter characters: \t");
scanf("--SPECIFIERS--");
```

So its not definite how much characters the user will enter.  I don't want my program to ask the user the 'numbers of characters'.. but I want to allow any the numbers of characters. But its not possible to enter infinite %c in scanf(). Can anyone tell me how to do that in C?

Comment: `%s` to read a string into a buffer.

Comment: @us2012: `%s` skips leading white space and stops at the first white space after a sequence of non-space characters.

Comment: Or simpler, replace `scanf(%s,s)` by `gets(s)`

Comment: How to use %s with characters & numbers??? Can u give an example plz? i m new to C.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon: go wash your mouth out with soap — or disinfectant if you've got some really nasty tasting stuff.  Do not ***ever*** recommend `gets()` to anyone.  It is not in standard C (C11) any more, and it is a security disaster.  Suggest `fgets()` by all means.

Comment: @user `%s` will read both characters and numbers just fine, but as Jonathan Leffler said, it will only read up to the first whitespace character.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You say 'infinite' but computers aren't infinite.  What are you after really?  You may find that the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function does what you want; it will allocate space until it comes across end of line.  You can usually use `fgets()` with a large buffer (eg `char line[4096]; if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ifp) != 0) { ...do stuff with line... }`).

Comment: never(!) use gets(). not even in a throw away example.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use infinite type specifiers (%c) in scanf() function.

You want to read an unspecified amount of data. There are a few approaches you can try:

- Use the POSIX standard [`getline(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function
- Use the POSIX standard `m` assignment-allocation in the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) family of functions

  ```
  char *str;
  scanf("%m[^\n]", &str);
  ```
- Read input one char at a time and grow a buffer as you go. There are a few functions floating about on stackoverflow, doing just this

The first 2 also allocate memory which you should `free(3)`.

Comment: This is great .. I wasn't aware of these.. So how would you free str ?

Comment: You can just do `free(str)`.

Comment: `free(str)` — just the same as any other dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Cool .. thanks for this handy little trick! .. So of course strlen(str) would work normally after scanning ?

Comment: @sukhvir The page Jonathan linked says: *which shall cause a memory buffer to be allocated to hold the string converted **including a terminating null character*** so that's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: ok.. can you tell what is the c program of finding avg of numbers given by the user (if you dont know how much nos. the user will give and u dnt want d program to ask 'how many nos.')? help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `%s` as qualifier for `scanf`. The one mentioned as below:

```
scanf("%s",buf);
```

where buf is of type:

```
char buf[100];
```

Comment: There's a deleted answer you can't see that says roughly what your answer says.  As noted in the comments to the question, the trouble with `%s` is that it skips leading white space and stops at the first white space after that.  Also, you should specify `"%99s"` if your buffer is 100 bytes long (and yes, there is an off-by-one here compared to most other functions).